# Replace string with special characters value using sed in Ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sed

Following is the xml file in which STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY should be replaced with EoKpaH0W/kqTv9awgIpQX5s+qQwGzXUSxMxhRjfSWG7SIUTWhut1OYQkNxhb3/9UKGf+g4tc3UaC0zKMTSrTNg==

```
   <property>
      <name>fs.azure.account.key.storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net</name>
      <value>STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY</value>
   </property>
```

I have tried the following. But nothing helps me solve it.

1. Using / after s and before g

> sed -i "s/STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY/EoKpaH0W/kqTv9awgIpQX5s+qQwGzXUSxMxhRjfSWG7SIUTWhut1OYQkNxhb3/9UKGf+g4tc3UaC0zKMTSrTNg==/g" test.xml

Error:-

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'
```

2. Using | after s and before g

> ```
> sed -i "s|STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY/EoKpaH0W/kqTv9awgIpQX5s+qQwGzXUSxMxhRjfSWG7SIUTWhut1OYQkNxhb3/9UKGf+g4tc3UaC0zKMTSrTNg==|g" test.xml
> ```

Error:-

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 112: unterminated `s' command
```

Note:- $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY is a dynamic variable as below

```
sed -i "s|STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY/$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY|g"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace XML, I would adivse to use an XML parser (for example `xmllint`) instead of `sed`.

That said, your `sed` expression is wrong.

`sed` `s` command uses 3 delimiters (any printable character you want), but these 3 must be the *same* and is defined by the one right after the `s` command.

```
s/foo/bar/g   # right
s|foo|bar|g   # right
s|foo/bar|g   # wrong
```

Since you replace a string with a base64 string, you should not use any of the base64 character, so don't use `/` as a `sed` delimiter in that case.

Your expression should be like this:

```
sed -i "s|STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY|EoKpaH0W/kqTv9awgIpQX5s+qQwGzXUSxMxhRjfSWG7SIUTWhut1OYQkNxhb3/9UKGf+g4tc3UaC0zKMTSrTNg==|g" test.xml
```

Note that the `g` modifier at the end of the command might not be necessary if you only have 1 string to replace per line.